# Since the conception of Set Theory, was Russell's Set the only problematic set found?

Tags: set-theory

I've read [the history section of Set Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#History) on wikipedia:

> The next wave of excitement in set theory came around 1900, when it was discovered that Cantorian set theory gave rise to several contradictions, called antinomies or paradoxes. Bertrand Russell and Ernst Zermelo independently found the simplest and best known paradox, now called Russell's paradox: consider "the set of all sets that are not members of themselves", which leads to a contradiction since it must be a member of itself, and not a member of itself. In 1899 Cantor had himself posed the question "What is the cardinal number of the set of all sets?", and obtained a related paradox. Russell used his paradox as a theme in his 1903 review of continental mathematics in his The Principles of Mathematics.

It mentions Russell's Paradox and Cantor's question as a related problem. It seems odd to me that only this set presented a problem - *mostly based on the naive heuristic which states that things present problems all the time* - and which I really think is not so naive. I've done some readings on set theory books (not very deep readings though) and Russell's set is always pointed as the problematic set. Are there other sets that also presented problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There were several paradoxes in early set theory:

1. **The set of all sets**, Cantor's proof that $|X|<|\mathcal P(X)|$ means that if $X$ is the set of all sets then $|\mathcal P(X)|\leq|X|$, which is a contradiction.

   In $\sf ZF$ this is resolved by not having the set of all sets; in set theories like $\sf NF$ where a universal set does exist, it is solved by other ways (e.g. making sure that the surjection from the universal set onto its power set, while definable, is not a set).
2. **The set of all ordinals**, Burali-Forti noted that if $X$ is the set of all ordinals, then $X$ is well-ordered, therefore an element of itself, and thus contradicting the fact that it is in fact well-ordered.

You may find more information in [this Wikipedia category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aParadoxes_of_naive_set_theory).

Comment: "making sure that the surjection ... is not a set". Is this a typo?

Comment: Why would it be a typo? (It might be a minor mistake of mine, or a misunderstanding of some sort; but it certainly read as it should read.)

Comment: Note that the rules of how to generate a set from other sets are different in $\sf NF$, and in particular not every definable subset of a set is a set itself.

Comment: Surely this is due to my lack of expertise in set theory but I was surprised that a function could be, or not be, a set. If this is what you meant, I must read more on these matters...

Comment: Did, in set theory... everything is a set. Including functions. Sometimes functions are not sets, but they are definable so we can talk about them in the appropriate way (i.e. class functions). But functions, much like everything else, are sets... (with the obvious exclusion of Chuck Norris. He's not a set.)

Comment: To declare in the same comment that everything is a set and that some functions are not sets is a bit fast for me. If you care to expand, I am sure your expertise will benefit many MSE users.

Comment: Did, of course. Things which exist are sets, so a function like $f(n)=n+1$ exists because it is a subset of $\Bbb{N\times N}$, and therefore a set. However I can also talk about the "function" $x\mapsto\mathcal P(x)$, or $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x\cup y$. But the domain of these functions is all the sets (or pairs of sets), and therefore not a set itself. So these functions are class-functions, rather than sets. But we can still define these "functions", which is why we can talk about them and treat them as functions in the usual sense of the word. But they don't exist per se. [...]

Comment: It would also be possible to confuse you some more and talk about "function symbols in the [extended] language of set theory". But let's not do that now. Instead, let me point out that set theory, as a foundational theory, is used to prove the existence of objects in "normal mathematics", and so proving that something exists is to say that it is a set. But being sufficiently strong, set theory can talk about set theory, so it can prove that some collections (which are not sets) behave like functions. We call these class-functions, and often omit the "class" part too.

Comment: To sum up, the surjection in part 1. of your answer is a class-function but not a function, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Aaaah... Thanks. :-)

Comment: [One can even notice the representation of a Pascal Triangle on Chuck Norris head. But he's obviously not a set.](http://youtu.be/T-D1KVIuvjA) I also present a [formal proof of this statement.](http://i.imgur.com/QEd3wtK.png)